# MySQL: How to have sum of each column for many columns

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table like this:

```
client_id | Product1 | Product2 | ... | Product170
--------------------------------------------------
4         |   Null   |   4      | ...  | 5 
32        |  5       |   3      | ...  | Null 
22        |  4       |  1       | ...  | 3
```

I want to have the **totals** for each of my Products. I want a view, or something similar, like this:

```
product_id | Total
--------------------------------------------------
Product1   |  9
Product2   |  8 
...
```

Preferably leaving out Products that have a sum of 0.

Am I able to do this? I have many columns so I would rather not have a SELECT statement calling each individual column by name.

(Context: This table holds orders for a business. A client will order some products and it is stored here. If you have a better way to organize this info, please let me know).

Comment: Using products as columns is a really, really bad design decision.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I agree, but I was unaware of any alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I able to do this?

Yes, by writing an extremely long query with `UNION`.

Example:

```
SELECT 'Product1' as product_id, SUM(Product1) as Total
FROM table
UNION
SELECT 'Product2' as product_id, SUM(Product2) as Total
FROM table
UNION
...
```

Obviously this is not practical, so...

> If you have a better way to organize this info, please let me know

A better way to organize this info would be to normalize it using a `products` table (with a unique id) and a junction table (e.g. `client_products`). This table contains 3 columns : `client_id`, `product_id` and `n` (the number of product, or whatever your number represents). The primary key is `(client_id, product_id)`, and add an index to `product_id`.

You can very easily query this model with `SELECT product_id, SUM(n) FROM client_products GROUP BY product_id`.

Comment: A junction table is perfect, thank-you! That makes a lot more sense and solves so many problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query like

```
SELECT sum(Product1) as Product1, sum(Product2) as Product1 FROM `product`
```

It will give you the total of each product but in one row and having product  name as column. You can also add the > 0 condition in where clause

Comment: There is a function to switch x and y axis of a table, but I do not remember the name..